# How to parse multiple values to a file using Stream Editor

Tags: sed

I have an XML file which requires 2 values to be passed dynamically. Can anyone please assist with my query.

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
sed s/a/$1/b/$2/g FILE_PATH/FILE_A_INPUT.xml > FILE_PATH/FILE_A.xml
```

Used the above function in .sh script, but it error-ed out.

```
RUN_THIS.sh 1 2
sed: Function s/a/1/g/b/2/g cannot be parsed
```

Comment: The sed command should be `sed s/something/other/g`, it is not clear what you want to do but you are using way too many `/`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Fedorqui. I want to replace a and b in an XML file by two inputs(as Command Line Arguments). Either one of the replacement works but is it possible to pass both the arguments. Hope that clears.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
sed "s/a/$1/g;s/b/$2/g" INPUT > OUTPUT
```

Instead.

Comment: In that case you might want to read this FAQ on have this site works, and accept the answer.